# JWT authentication does not work in Django Rest Framework after deploying it to IIS on live server

Tags: python, django, windows, iis, django-rest-framework

I built a Rest API using Django's Rest framework. And I've deployed it on Windows OS's IIS. When I deploy the application to the live IIS server, it throws the following issue even though it functions well on the local IIS server. I have used [wfastcgi](https://pypi.org/project/wfastcgi/) package for deploying my application to IIS.

DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES in `settings.py`:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
}
```

Here's an example request in postman:
[image]

Comment: You can try adding "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES" to your settings.py. It might work.

Comment: @TengFeiXie I have already added that but it's still not working

Comment: I would recommend providing an example request (curl or httpie are what I'd typically use for testing out requests) with the sensitive information redacted to aid in troubleshooting. As posted, this question is too vague to be able to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the error was in `settings.py` file because I haven't updated the `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS` so I changed it as below:

Here's the snippet of code on my local machine

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
]
```

Here's the snippet of code on my live server,

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "https://www.example.com"
]
```